# How to check that 2 strings are actually equal and have same characters? Even with spacing or lowercase

Tags: java, arrays, string

Can anyone help me? I am trying to compare 2 strings if its equal or not (without considering spaces and cases)

Examples:

> "Abc1", "Abc1 " -> true (with spacing at the end)
>
> "Abc1", "abc1"  -> true (with lowercase)
>
> "Abc1", " Abc1 " -> true (with spacing at the beginning and at the end
> of the string)
>
> "Abc1", " abc1 " -> true (with lowercase and spacing at the beginning
> and at the end of the string)

It should have the same order, and if its not the same order, it will returns false

> "Abc1", "Ac1b " -> false

I already tried this code, but it didnt give me the result I was looking for

```
public static boolean sameChars(String firstStr, String secondStr) {
    char[] first = firstStr.toCharArray();
    char[] second = secondStr.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(first);
    Arrays.sort(second);
    return Arrays.equals(first, second);
}
```

Comment: *it should have the same order,* - why sort then?

Comment: `a.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(b.trim())` - [JavaDocs for `String`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html)

Comment: ^ What they said :) That's all there is to it.

Comment: What about spaces within the string? IE is `"abc1"` considered equal to `"ab c1"`?

Answer (score 3):

If your intention is only to compare then there's no need to convert the string to a char array.

To ignore spaces at the beginning and end of the strings use `trim()`

Ex:

`firstStr.trim()`

To compare ignoring cases use `equalsIgnoreCase()`

Ex:

`firstStr.equalsIgnoreCase(secondStr)`

If you want to ignore all spaces in the string, even if it is within the string, you will have to use `replace(char oldchar, char newchar)` rather than `trim()`.

Ex:

`firstStr.replace(" ","")`

Assuming you only want to ignore the spaces in the beginning and end, to compare do:
`firstStr.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(secondStr.trim())`

If you want to ignore all spaces:

`firstStr.replace(" ", "").equalsIgnoreCase(secondStr.replace(" ", "")`